# $\|(x, y)\| = \sqrt{ax^2 + bxy + cy^2}$; find conditions on $a, b, c$ for the function being a norm

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $a , b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z = (x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} $, then we define $$\|z\|_s := \sqrt{ax^2 + bxy + cy^2}$$
Now what conditions do $a, b, c$ have to fulfill so that $\|z\|_s$ becomes a norm?

I tried using triangle inequality to get more information without success.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: shouldn't $a, b, c$ be nonnegative?

Comment: @enedil: $a$ and $c$ yes, $b$ no.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, even a and c can be negative

Comment: @Chiray: That isn't true.  If either is negative your expression will sometimes be imaginary.

Comment: @JonasMeyer ok I see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b/2\\ 
b/2 & c
\end{bmatrix}$ and define $\left \langle x,y  \right \rangle_{s}=x^tAy$, for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $\|x\|_{s}^{2}=\left \langle x,x  \right \rangle_{s}$.

Then, $\|\cdot\|_{s}$ is norm iff ($\|\cdot\|_{s}\geq0$  and $\|x\|_{s}=0$ iff $x=0$) iff $A$ is positive-definite.

Comment: Thank you! Do you call that $< , >$ Dot product in english? And now the only thing do to is to find out when $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is greater than 0, and that can be done with the determinant and the eigenvalue. Is this correct?

Comment: @Chiray: It is equivalent to $a>0$, $c>0$, and $ac-\frac14 b^2>0$ (although $c>0$ is redundant).  It is also equivalent to both eigenvalues of $A$ being positive.